# Express.js session cookies do not work with secure=true in CloudFront

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-cloudfront

To make my webapp ready for production, I wanted to set the session cookie property "secure" from false to true. 
The app is hosted by Aws and is built like this:

Route53 -> CloudFront -> ELB (no cluster, only SingleApp)

CloudFront is used to make the app accessible via SSL. The Nodejs app listens on an HTTP port.
Unfortunately the SessionCookie is not set.

If I set secure to false, the login works and the session cookie is set. So it only seems to depend on this property.
I also set "trust proxy" to true, but unfortunately without success.

Express.js:

```
const ExpressApp=express();
ExpressApp.set("trust proxy", (ip)=>{
    return true;
  });
...
```

session:

```
  const expiryDate = new Date( Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000 ); // 1 hour
        return session({
            genid: (req) => {
                return uuid() // use UUIDs for session IDs
            },
            secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: true,        
            proxy:true,    
            store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
            rolling: true,
            cookie:{
                secure:true,
                httpOnly:true,
                expires: expiryDate
            }
        })
```

CloudFront:
 https://pasteboard.co/Ib9mTED.png